# How do I pass incoming call info to a Visualforce page when I pop before answer?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, opencti, call-center

I'm just starting on this experiment, so much ignorance here. I have ported my company's call center to SF and if the incoming caller ID matches a contact, it can pop to that contact's page fine. I'm experimenting with VF and wonder if there's a way to pass the caller ID to a VF page so the contact info could eventually be displayed there.

Comment: did you find the solution? i also looking for same issue

Comment: I'm sorry, no, I never did get any replies on this (thanks a lot, forum). And since this was a zero-priority experiment, I never followed up on it.